# Using Simple Webaudiorecorder.js in R/Shiny and posting the recording to the server

Tags: javascript, shiny, xmlhttprequest, blob, wav

I am using WebAudioRecorder.js for making online recordings in an R Shiny app, see:

https://github.com/addpipe/simple-web-audio-recorder-demo

As a format, I chose the wave format, and in the JavaScript code, the recording is obtained as a blob. I would like the program to save this blob on the server without any dialog.

Comment: Do you want to save it on the local computer or upload it to the server?

Comment: You can't post something to a blob url...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you shouldn't set the hole filePath in javascript, you should give it a filename and then php should put it in the correct folder.

```
function uploadWaveBlob (blob, encoding) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var formData = new FormData();
  var fileName = Date().toISOString() + '.' + encoding;

  formData.append("Wav", blob, fileName);

  xhr.open('POST', uploadUrl);

  xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log('xhr complete');
  };

  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

imagine if i would upload something to like `/etc/hosts` or something

Comment: the url to your php script that should handle file upload

Answer (score 1):

The following site gives code that shows how to upload a blob to the server:

https://gist.github.com/primaryobjects/d6cdf5d31242a629b0e4cda1bfc4bff9

The complete solution is available at:

https://github.com/heeringa0/simple-web-audio-recorder

and shows how to integrate the Simple WebAudioRecorder.js in an R Shiny app where the recording is saved to the server.